# How to stub Intent.createChooser Intent using Espresso

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

**Problem**

I have an image inside my app, and am sharing it to any other app that can handle image sharing, and the feature is working perectlty.

I am writing an Espresso UI test to intercept the intent and ensure it has the correct action and extras, but cannot seem to get it to work.

**Code**

Here is the code when creating the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType(MediaType.PNG.toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "send");
```

and here is my attempt to match the Intent in my test, but fails to find a match:

```
Intents.init();
launchActivity(MyFragment.newIntent(getTargetContext());

Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = allOf(
    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER),
    hasExtra(
        Intent.ACTION_SEND,
        hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, EXPECTED_SHARE_URI) // Expected URI has been copied from the extras 'uriString' value when debugging
    )
);
intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));
MyScreen.clickShareButton(); // performs click on the share button
intended(expectedIntent);
Intents.release();
```

**Error**

`IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.CHOOSER" and has extras: has bundle with: key: is "android.intent.extra.STREAM" value: is "[my uri appears here]")`

**Additional info**

When debugging, the intent that is created results in an intent with action "android.intent.action.CHOOSER", and has an extra of type Intent, with action "android.intent.action.SEND" and type "image/png", and in turn has an extra, a HierarchicalUri with a uriString.

**Summary**

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I can't find a way to tie all this together and create a matcher for this intent. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error on this line `intended(expectedIntent)` because the intent didn't match, it's probably because `Intent.createChooser` put your intent as an extra data with the key `Intent.EXTRA_INTENT`. In your case, you only need an extra intent matcher for the chooser:

```
Matcher<Intent> intent = allOf(
    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND),
    hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, EXPECTED_SHARE_URI)
);

Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = allOf(
    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER),
    // Intent.createChooser put your intent with the key EXTRA_INTENT
    hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, intent)
);

intending(anyIntent()).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));

MyScreen.clickShareButton();

intended(expectedIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however unfortunately this did not fix the problem. As it turns out, the fix was for each time `hasExtra()` was used, the first parameter (Intent type) needed to be wrapped inside an `equalTo()`, so this has now been resolved :)

Comment: Yeah wow just spent 60 minutes on the same problem with my matcher, thanks Mate @Ry